# How can I create a new column in a pandas data frame by extracting words from sentences in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe like this.

```
import pandas as pd
student_id = ['001', '002', '003', '004']
names = ['Jane', 'Mary', 'Andrew', 
'Paul']
address = ['7 karumu st Ikeja Lagos', '8 
logo street Umuahia Abia', 
       '10 jege close PH Rivers', '9 
Lekki gate Lagos']

test_1 = {'Student_ID': student_id, 
      'Name': names, 
      'Address': address}
df = pd.DataFrame(test_1)
df`
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcxAi.png)

and a list like this:

```
List = [Imo, Lagos, Abia, Ebonyi, Rivers]
```

So i am trying to iterate through the Address column and estract the states in the address which is also in the list. If a state in the list is spotted I would like to extract it and append to a new column called state.

I tried to use the iterrows() method but I am a bit lost

Comment: It's better not to use `List` as a variable name because it's a Python keyword to design the `List` type.

Comment: Edited my answer [fixed] to put only the state in the new column (instead of the whole address).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the state is always the last word in the address.

```py
import numpy as np

states = ["Imo", "Lagos", "Abia", "Ebonyi", "Rivers"]
df["State"] = df["Address"].map(lambda x: state if (state:=x.split()[-1]) in states else np.nan)
```

Comment: Hi thanks but this returned a new column with the same addresses

Comment: Edited to make it work. Use the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=walrus#assignment-expressions) to assign the last word to the `state` variable (in order to avoid repetition).

Comment: Thanks a lot this actually worked. Luckily most of the rows have the state as the last word.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter like this:

```
df = df[df['Address'].str.contains('|'.join(List))]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response but I am a bit confused with the "|" what is supposed to be in the quotes?  Does this line of code create a new column?

Comment: The '|' stands for 'or'

Comment: df['State'] = df[df['Address'].str.contains[........

Comment: The data is large with over 4 million rows

Answer (score 0):

- get the 'Adress' Column
- convert to 'List' to DataFrame
- After I think 'MERGE' you should use
- Storage to last dafaFrame and add the as a another column

I think this will solve your problem

Comment: While this provides guidance, I think having code to go along with your answer would be more helpful